# messageCollectionView in MessageKit not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, messagekit

I'm new to Xcode development and very new to MessageKit. I'm currently following an iOS Academy video to get the messaging section of my app working (Great series of videos by the way).

I have installed the MessageKit cocoa pod (and reinstalled it like 3 times to make sure I did it right) but yet, I can't seem to use the `messagesCollectionView` property.

I know it exists because first, the tutorial uses it, and second, after further investigation, ITS THE FIRST ATTRIBUTE OF THE VIEW CONTROLLER

```
open class MessagesViewController: UIViewController,
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    /// The `MessagesCollectionView` managed by the messages view controller object.
    open var messagesCollectionView = MessagesCollectionView()

    /// The `InputBarAccessoryView` used as the `inputAccessoryView` in the view controller.
    open lazy var messageInputBar = InputBarAccessoryView()
```

when I start typing out "messagesCollectionView" there is no autocomplete and I get an error that says that it cannot be found in scope. Here is my view controller

```
class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {
    let currentUser = Sender(senderId: "self",displayName: "Yianni Zavaliagkos")
    let otherUser = Sender(senderId: "other",displayName: "Ezra Taylor")
    
    var messages: [MessageType] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Chat"
        
        messages.append(Message(sender: currentUser,
                                messageId: "1",
                                sentDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-86400),
                                kind: .text("Hello World")))
        
        messages.append(Message(sender: otherUser,
                                messageId: "2",
                                sentDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-70000),
                                kind: .text("How is it going")))
        
        //Errors on these next couple lines
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    }


}
```

and yes, I have implemented the MessegesDataSource and Layout and Display Delegates as well.

My first guess is that I installed the cocoa pod somehow incorrectly but I've tried everything and was hoping to be blessed by the StackOverflow Gods with an easy solution to this frustrating problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please add `ErrorMessage`, it seems to be right everything.

Comment: @Yianni_Zav Use SPM to install the dependency and it will work, it's included in the example source too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload your collection, so put: messagesCollectionView.reloadData() to your viewDidLoad method. It works for me